# Error after opening Fancybox link

Tags: jquery, plugins, fancybox

I'm getting an error when I click on a Fancybox link. The plugin works as far as displaying the boxes, but after initializing one of them I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (plugins.js:1983)
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (script.js:6)
```

I'm using a very basic setup for the boxes -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

Using jQuery 1.9.0 and FancyBox 2.1.4. Plugin is loaded (in plugins.js) before script.js which runs it. Am I missing something? The document ready function is at line 6 in script.js.

Comment: did you make sure that you declare the script of jquery before the fancybox js files calls ?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the correct order.

Comment: one more check, are you sure that you are using only on source of jquery?

Comment: Yes. I've checked for file ordering / plugin references already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this script in the beginning of the your page.

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        var jquery = document.createElement("script");
        jquery.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        jquery.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
        scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(jquery, scripts);
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe a little on how to use it and what it does?

Comment: sure, this will check if jQuery is loaded in the page, and if not it'll add a script tag in the html to call and request jquery.

Comment: Thanks. I just found out what was causing it, I forgot to remove footer links to the scripts in the iframe... So it tried executing twice.